# Regular expression validate form

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation

I can not figure out how can I put 5 characters that has `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, and can include `$` and `@` with regex. This is what I have

```
$char_regex = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9@\$]{5}$/';
```

it keeps showing error.

Comment: Please, provide examples of correct and incorrect inputs for your form.

Comment: regex works for me. Please provide an [MCVE] so we can reproduce your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *positive lookaheads*:

```
$char_regex = '/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9@\$]{5}$/';
```

Explaining:

```
^                     # from start
(?=.*[a-z])           # means should exist one [a-z] character in some place
(?=.*[A-Z])           # same to upper case letters
(?=.*[0-9])           # same to digits
[a-zA-Z0-9@\$]{5}$    # your current regex
```

Hope it helps.